# Heap error during cout C++

Tags: c++, cout, heap-corruption

I'm getting an error when trying to cout the return value of Data[index].  If anyone could help me that would be awesome.  I know usually these errors are caused by allocated conflicting memory or having a pointer reference a deleted index, etc.  Although I don't delete anything so I don't know where this error is coming from.

**Header file:**

```
#pragma once
#define INITIAL_CAPACITY 100
#define CAPACITY_BOOST 40


//Encapsulates the C-array
template <typename DATA_TYPE>
class Vector
{
public:
//Default / init-constructor hybrid
Vector(int initialCapacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY)
{
    Size=0;
    Capacity = initialCapacity;

    //Allocate the encapsulated C-array
    Data= new DATA_TYPE[Size];
}

//MUST HAVE A COPY-CONSTRUCTOR THAT PERFORMS deep-copy
Vector(const Vector& copyFrom)
{
    //Necessary to prevent assignment operator from crashing
    //because it will attempt to Delete[] Data whe the Data pointer is garbage.
    Data=NULL;
    //Use assignment operator to perform the deep copy
    *this = copyFrom;
}


//The class MUST have a destructor
~Vector()
{
    //Deallocate memory that our class has allocated
    delete[] Data;
}
//MUST have an assignment operator that performs deep copy
Vector& operator =(const Vector& copyFrom)
{
    //0. Delete the old memory
    delete[] Data;
    //1. Copy size and Capacity
    Size = copyFrom.Size;
    Capacity = copyFrom.Capacity;
    //2. Allocate Memory
    Data = new DATA_TYPE[Capacity];
    //3. Copy elemenets
    for(int i=0; i < Size; i++)
        Data[i]= copyFrom.Data[i];

    //All assignment operators should return *this
    return *this;
}

//Get accessors to return the values of Size and Capacity
int GetSize() const
{
    return this->Size;
}

int GetCapacity() const
{
    return Capacity;
}

void Insert(int insertAt, const DATA_TYPE& newElement)
{
    //**ASSIGNMENT**
    //1. Determine if we have enough capacity for extra element(reallocate)
    Size=GetSize();
    if(Size>=Capacity)
    {
        Capacity += CAPACITY_BOOST;
    }
    //Use a function to check bounds.

    if((insertAt > Capacity)||(insertAt < 0))
    {
        throw "Index is out of bounds";
    }
    //2.Move the tail
    for (int i=Size+1; i > insertAt; i--)
        Data[i]=Data[i-1];

    //3.Insert element
    Data[insertAt]= newElement;

}
//Inserts a new element at the end fo the Vector and increments the size
void Add(const DATA_TYPE& newElement)
{

    Insert(Size, newElement);
    Size++;
}

void Remove(int index)
{
    delete Data[index];
    for(i=index; i < Size-1; i++)
        Data[i]=Data[i+1];
    Size--;
    Capacity=Size;
    //**ASSIGNMENT**
    //Resize. Shrink vector when you have too much capacity
    //TEST EVERYTHING
}

// Index operator
DATA_TYPE operator[] (int index) const
{
    // Check the bounds and throw an exception
    if ( (index < 0) || (index >= Size) )
        throw "Error";

    return Data[index];
}


private:
//The count of actually used C-array elements
int Size;
//The count of the allocated C-array elements
int Capacity;
//The encapsulated C-array (pointer)

DATA_TYPE* Data;
};
```

**Main:**

```
    #include <iostream>
#include "vector.h"
using namespace std;

#define TEST_CAPACITY 100
#define TEST_SIZE 10

template<typename DATA_TYPE>
void PassByValueTest(Vector<DATA_TYPE>passedByValue)
{
}
void main()
{
//myVector is initialized using the default constructor
Vector<int> myVector;

//Populate myVector with some test values
for (int i=0; i< TEST_SIZE; i++)
    myVector.Add(i);

//myOtherVector initialized using the init-constructor, initial capacity is 10
//Vector<int> myOtherVector(TEST_CAPACITY);


//Test by passing vector by value
/*
PassByValueTest(myVector);

myVector = myOtherVector;
*/
for(int i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; i++)
{
    cout << myVector[i];
}
system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should switch:

```
Data= new DATA_TYPE[Size];
```

to

```
Data= new DATA_TYPE[Capacity];
```

Answer (score 1):

you are doing `Data = new DATA_TYPE[0];`

```
Vector(int initialCapacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY)
{
    Size=0;                    // <<<---
    Capacity = initialCapacity;

    //Allocate the encapsulated C-array
    Data= new DATA_TYPE[Size];  // note Size is 0
}
```

Then access to `Data[i]` is undefined behavior:

```
for(int i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; i++)
{
    cout << myVector[i];
}
```

Side note, you should return int from main, there is no `void main` in standard:

```
int main()
{
}
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with allocating an array of size 0.  you need to point out where **the** problem is...